# GStreamer plugin usage in Haskell

Tags: haskell, opengl, plugins, gstreamer

I'm trying to get the image from a webcam with GStreamer and load it to an OpenGL texture.

I'm using the [gstreamer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gstreamer-0.12.5.0) haskell library. I managed to simply display the webcam output in a window with `v4l2src` as a source and `xvimagesink` as a sink. Now I'd like to load this in an OpenGL texture. I saw you can do this in C with the [appsink](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-appsink.html#gst-app-sink-pull-sample) GStreamer plugin that allows you to extract samples from the pipeline by calling `gst_app_sink_pull_sample ()`.

I think I managed to load the `app` plugin and the `appsink` feature but I don't know what is the equivalent of `gst_app_sink_pull_sample ()` in Haskell.

This is how I load the `app` plugin and the `appsink` feature:

```
import qualified Media.Streaming.GStreamer as GS

main = do
    GS.init
    appPlugin <- GS.pluginLoadByName "app"
    appsinkFeature <- GS.registryLookupFeature GS.defaultRegistry "appsink"
```

Should I create an `Element` like this:

```
appSink <- GS.elementFactoryMake "appsink" (Just "app-sink")
```

But what do I do with it after to sample the pipeline?

Comment: @ElleGnrd and potential answerers: Note that C answers *might* be helpful here. The *gstreamer* Haskell library appears to be a thin wrapper over the [core GStreamer library](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-libs/html/). If there are no Haskell bindings for the GStreamer plugin Elle needs, and if there is a way of answering the question using only the core libraries, a (largely) direct translation from C to Haskell should be possible. I unfortunately can't help much further, as I know very little about the GStreamer libraries in either language.

Comment: It's not part of the Haskell bindings it seems, and dynamic GLib action signal usage does not seem possible (correct me if I'm wrong please). It would have to be added to the bindings first.

But independent of that, the Haskell GStreamer bindings are for the old 0.10 release series of GStreamer, which is no longer maintained since 3 years. And especially for anything OpenGL related, the latest 1.6 version should be used.

Comment: For a C example, see here http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/tree/tests/examples/app/appsink-src.c#n52 . But that's probably not very useful for you as you seem to know how to do it from C :)

Comment: I think it's possible to use [GLib](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/glib-0.13.2.1/docs/System-Glib-Signals.html) signals with the GStreamer Haskell library but I have no idea how to do this. The signal concept is quite new to me and I don't really know where to start. Any suggestion? Thanks for your insight anyway.

Comment: There's only API to connect to signals as far as I can see, what you need here is to be able to emit signals.